# Выполнение php-скрипта локально

Tags: php

Здравствуйте, народ. У меня проблема с php. Установлен сервер Apache 2.2, но когда открываю php-скрипт на локалке, браузер видит код php как текст. Что делать?
Я понимаю, что такое серверные скрипты.

Comment: Заряд хорошего настроения на весь день - пишите ещё) ПС а сам PHP установлен?

Comment: кремчик +1!!!

Comment: @Shrek, ахах, отредактировали авторский стиль письма, сразу всё веселье пропало)

Comment: хе хе вам весело да ребята?!

Comment: а никто не хочет помогать мне?

Comment: EEE Okazovayetsya chto nado bilo rasskomentirovat v php.ini
Shorttags i style ASP. Ostalnimotdix!)))

Answer (score 1):

> я понимаю что такое серверские скрипти

Серверные скрипты никак не  "серверские скрипти"

По ходу не понимаешь. :)

```
.htaccess
AddHandler application/x-httpd-php .php
```

Comment: на конфиг файле есть такая строка
PhpIniDir "C:/php"
LoadModule php5_module "C:/php/php5apache2_2.dll"
AddHandler application/x-httpd-php .php

 но .htaccess вот я не понимаю ну где же этот файл?

Comment: винда у меня 64 битная

Comment: В корень сайта его кинь.

Сам его создай.

Comment: Shrek, спасибо, я все исправил, во всем виноват был рнр.ini (open shorttags) помимо серверных скриптов есть и еще клиентские скрипты!

Comment: xex, прочитав сегодня свои старые сообщения - просто стало весело - сколько времени прошли...